# How to calculate the reactance of a capacitor with an input signal that is 2 sin waves of difference frequencies added together?

Tags: capacitor, reactance

I am trying to calculate the reactance of a capacitor with an input signal that is not a single frequency.  For example, x = sin(4t)+sin(5t), or a capacitor that is used in an audio circuit like the following:
[image]

I found the following equation to calculate reactance:
$$ X_C = 1/(2*pi*f*c) $$
but I don't know what to use for the frequency.

Is there a better way to calculate this?

PS, what I'm doing in the long run is trying to calculate what the voltage will be at pin 3 if VIN is the output of my Arudino Due DAC that's supposed to have a max voltage around 2.5V

Comment: Superposition theorem.

Comment: @LongPham I'm confused as to exactly what you mean.  Are you saying I should just calculate the reactance for each frequency in the signal separate?

Comment: You should focus on how a system responses to input signal rather than a single component. For example, the input R and C in your circuit form a high pass filter.